# How can I rewrite this jQuery code into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a WordPress theme that only has about 10 lines of jQuery, yet it's using the 90kb jQuery file. I want to change this jQuery code to Javascript, but I'm not very good at Javascript:

```
jQuery('body #main-tabbed-area a, body .wp-pagenavi a, body .pagination a').live("click", function () {
  $href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
  $contentArea.fadeTo('fast', 0.2).load($href + ' #main-area', function () {
    $contentArea.fadeTo('fast', 1);
  });
  return false;
});


var $tabbed_area = jQuery('div#tabbed');
if ($tabbed_area.length) {
  $tabbed_area.tabs({
    fx: {
      opacity: 'toggle'
    }
  });
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: jQuery is already written in Javascript. I guess what you wanna achieve is removing 90kb jQuery lib dependency. Unfortunately, if you wanna rewrite that in your own code, that would most likely result in 90kb+ equivalent of Javascript lines

Comment: please don't vote this one down.  Thanks to some of the answers it's an excellent learning tool for teaching why we use jquery.

Comment: The 90Kb jQuery library is what makes those 10 lines function.  If we could simply rewrite them without jQuery then why use jQuery in the first place, is what you should ask yourself.

Comment: But those 10 lines can be replaced by about 100 lines of plain javascript, so 4,000 lines of jQuery can be removed.

Comment: @RobG:  Maybe or maybe not.  Let's not forget it still has to be thoroughly tested cross platform/browser.  Is writing/testing a couple hundred lines of JavaScript from scratch really worth the tiny, almost insignificant benefit of not loading 90Kb?

Comment: The code written to replace jQuery here can be used elsewhere, it doesn't need to be re-written every time. Any reasonable development groupd should be able to do it in an hour or so and have it available as drop-in code after that. Also, the jQuery code must be tested too so not a real issue there. jQuery supports only recent versions of a small number of browsers (5). Try StackOverflow (a jQuery based site) in IE 6 - it's disfunctional to the point of being unusable.

Comment: @RobG:  IE 6 is dysfunctional to the point of being unusable.  And now it's a 10-year-old browser for crying out loud!

Comment: @Sparky - and it is **still** the corporate standard at the site I currently work at. I don't use it for the web,  but regular users do. My point is really that using a "cross browser" library doesn't necessarily mean that your site will work, even in the small number of browsers the library claims to support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I'd persist with jQuery. Although there is "only about 10 lines jQuery" what it is doing is quite substantial. By the time you have recreated a lot of what jQuery is providing you here you will have a fairly decent slab of javaScript to debug and maintain. That is the beauty of jQuery, to quote their tag line "write less, do more" Remember with jQuery you are eliminating a lot of annoying cross browser quirks.

**Edit:** See [tbranyen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604888/how-can-i-rewrite-this-jquery-code-into-javascript/6605175#6605175) for a practical example of why jQuery is worth it

Use a CDN version of jQuery, like [Google's](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery) and you will be using jQuery that your uses may already have cached and therefore does not have to be downloaded again. jQuery UI can also be served in the same way. See this article: http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

**EDIT**

Reading your question further "I'm not very good at javaScript" is all the more reason to stick with jQuery. Let it do all the heaving lifting for you. **HOWEVER** don't use jQuery as an excuse not to learn more about javaScript, the more you learn about javaScript the more you will be able to get out of jQuery.

Comment: 32kb is the "transfer size" of the file over the internet (minified + gzipped), actual minified version is about 90kb

Comment: Thanks Neverever, I'll adjust my answer accordingly

Comment: @Neverever: Sneaky! Didn't know they measured it that way.

Comment: +1 on keep learning Javascript, although it seems like the deeper you get into it, the more you understand how Javascript does things.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is fragmented, its not complete, and I do not expect points for this answer.  This was me taking a stab at replicating jQuery's code in vanilla JS, purely as scientific justice to your question.  I consider myself good at JavaScript, but even I know my limitations and time constraints.  I only have one life on this planet and its honestly not worth my time to write out a tabs plugin and animation for your Wordpress site.

Just take a look at the code difference.  If you're really scared about people downloading, you should ask yourself what makes your site so much different than the thousands/millions? of other sites that are visited by millions of people?

Writing this stuff is tedious, that's why if I have to do these things, I use jQuery.  **However**, lets say you don't care about older browser support.  You didn't mention that, I have a solution at the very bottom that does more, but **WILL** not work with older browsers or work period for that matter.

**The original**

Very little code to do immensely complicated stuff.

```
jQuery('body #main-tabbed-area a, body .wp-pagenavi a, body .pagination a').live("click", function () {
  $href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
  $contentArea.fadeTo('fast', 0.2).load($href + ' #main-area', function () {
    $contentArea.fadeTo('fast', 1);
  });
  return false;
});
```

**Attempting to write from scratch**

```
// Not even close to finished solution
(function(window, document) {
  var tabbed = document.getElementById('tabbed');

  // Semi-normalized event handling, not even a fraction as good as jQuery's
  function attachEvent(node, type, callback) {
    if(node.attachEvent) {
      return node.attachEvent('on'+type, function() {
        callback.apply(window.event.target, arguments);
      });
    }

    return node.addEventListener(type, function(e) {
      callback.apply(e.target, arguments);
    }, true);
  }

  // Semi-delegation again, not even a fraction of what jQuery offers
  attachEvent(document, 'click', function(e) {
    var href = this.href;
    var body = document.body;
    var elements = [];
    var slice = [].slice;
    var concat = elements.concat;

    // This is just the start of what it would take to emulate what jQuery is doing to match all those items
    // Without a reliable selector engine like querySelectorAll (not even that reliable) you'd need to match.
    elements = concat(slice.call(body.getElementById('main-tabbed-area').getElementsByTagName('a')));
    elements = concat(slice.call(body.getElementsByTagName('...');

    // Not even going to attempt fading
    // jQuery again does all this
  });

  if(tabbed && tabbed.tagName === 'div') {
    // No idea what tabs is? A plugin? Good luck!
  }

})(this, this.document);
```

**Code is slightly more modern... but still jeesh look at all that code**

```
function xhr(url, callback) {
  var request = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if(e.readyState === 4) {
      callback(e.responseXML);
    }
  };
  request.send(null);
}

// No idea what contentArea is
var contentArea = ...???;

(function(window, document) {
  var tabbed = document.getElementsById('tabbed');

  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var href;
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('body #main-tabbed-area a, body .wp-pagenavi a, body .pagination a');
    var match = false;

    elements.forEach(function(element) {
      if(this === element) {
        match = true;
      }
    });

    if(match) {
      href = e.target.href;

      // Some CSS3 class that does a fade out
      contentArea.classList.add('fadeOut');

      xhr(href, function(data) {
        var data = data.getElementById('main-area').innerHTML;
        contentArea.innerHTML = data;

        contentArea.classList.remove('fadeOut');

        // Some CSS3 class that does a fade in
        contentArea.classList.add('fadeIn');
      });

      return false;
    }
  }, true);

  if(tabbed && tabbed.tagName === 'div') {
    // Still no idea what tabs is? A plugin? Good luck!
  }
})(this, this.document);
```

Comment: +1 for clearly demonstrating that jQuery is not there for nothing.

Comment: agreed +1 to help a noob understand WHY jquery is worth the price...oh and I know I'm good at javascript but you look like the guy I go to for answers.

Comment: + 1 For illustrating the succinctness of jQuery

Comment: Good to show 4,500 lines of code can be replaced by less than 100. But please fix `document.getElementsById('tabbed')` (there is no **s**). Perhaps you meant `getElementsByClassName`, I can post a 10 line version if you need that for browsers that don't support the host method.

Comment: Thanks @RobG, fixed that typo.  Nah it was id, according to the OP.  I'd like to keep writing the rest of this code, but it just feels wrong :-p